# how i can change the background color of navigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

In my navigation bar i have two button at left and right position and a segmentetControll view at navigation title.
I want to change the background color of the navigation bar to black but thae color of the items on it will be another color.
how can i do it?
I try to chnage the tintColor of the navigationBar to black.
but i show that the color of the segmentedControll and the button on the navigationBar also changed to black.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

try to set the objects as subviews to the navigationBar.

Set the tint color

```
UINavigationController *theNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: aFeedControler]; 
theNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Add the segmentedControl as a subview in the viewControllers like this:

```
 UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_check.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_search.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_tools.png"], nil]];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 200,40);
    segmentedControl.frame = frame;
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;  
    self.navigationItem.titleView  = segmentedControl;
```

For the buttons you should try creating UIButtons not UIBarButtonsItems and add them as subviews also. If you create UIBarButtonsItems and add them like this self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = tempButton; you will get the effect that you saw.

if you add them as subviews you shouldn't have the problem you mentioned.. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have the property called tintColor in navigation bar. You can set its value to any colour.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UINavigationController *_navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: _viewController]; 

 either this
 _navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

 OR 
_navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlack;



 Now about right and left buttons:
 UIButton *btnLeft=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 btnLeft.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 5.0, 50.0, 30.0);
 btnLeft.backgroundColor=[UIColor RedColor];
 btnLeft.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
 btnLeft.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
 btnLeft.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0];

 _navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btnLeft];



 similary you can add right bar button
```